# XMLHttpRequest fails to send certain PDFs, nothing happens after loadstart

Tags: javascript, pdf, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I want to upload (PDF-)files to my server, sending the files from a file-input to a JS-function that sends a XMLHttpRequest. Although it works with lots of PDFs up to 32MB filesize, it sometimes doesn't work with much smaller ones (e.g. 4MB filesize).

Here's the JS-function, equipped with EventListeners finding the error:

```
function uploadFiles(input_id) {
    const input = document.getElementById(input_id);
    const files = input.files;
    if (files.length == 0) {
        alert("No Files selected!");
        return;
    }

    let formData = new FormData();
    for (let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        formData.append(i, files[i]);
    }
    console.log(formData);
    
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.addEventListener("error", handleEvent);
        request.addEventListener("loadstart", handleEvent);
        request.addEventListener("load", handleEvent);
        request.addEventListener("loadend", handleEvent);
        request.addEventListener("progress", handleEvent);
        request.addEventListener("error", handleEvent);
        request.addEventListener("abort", handleEvent);
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                resolve(this.responseText);
            } else {
                return this.responseText;
            }
        }
        request.open("POST", "includes/fileUpload.inc.php");
        request.send(formData);
    } );
}

function handleEvent(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

And here's the targeted php-file for testing:

```
<?php
echo "hi";
return;
```

The PDFs do make it into the FormData. When it works, the file-upload takes a few seconds, then gets resolved with "hi". When it doesn't work, the "loadstart"-EventListener fires, nothing happens for about (but not exactly) 60 seconds, then the "progress"-, "error"- and "loadend"-EventListeners fire. I get no errors, none of the console.logs give me any information that is useful to me, no response-values or anything.

I tried it in Chrome and in Firefox, they both fail at the same PDFs.

The upload works when packing the PDFs into a .rar-archive, so it seems to be PDF-specific.

I also tried replacing the XMLHttpRequest-Promise with jQuery's .ajax() in following manner, the same PDFs fail to upload:

```
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "includes/fileUpload.inc.php",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Since most similar problems failed because of the php.ini, here are my settings (I don't think it's PHP's fault though):

- memory_limit: 256M
- max_execution_time: 600
- max_input_time: 60
- post_max_size: 96M
- upload_max_filesize: 96M

How can I find more information to trace the error back?

Comment: So you see NOTHING in the network panel?

Comment: @epascarello After ~60 seconds the value in "Transferred" is "NS_ERROR_NET_RESET". The headers seem to be correct: "Accept-Encoding" is "gzip, deflate", "Content-Type" is "multipart/form-data [...]"
Other than that I can't find anything interesting, except maybe under the "time"-tab it says "blocked: 48,55s" and "sending: 53,72s" even though it only took 70 seconds in total. But I'm not very familiar with the network panel, is there a certain thing I should look out for?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found any solutions?

Comment: @Elembivios sadly no :(